# Как изменить кодировку всего приложения?

Tags: кодировка, javascript, java

Здравствуйте.
Как перекодировать все приложение из Windows-1251 в UTF-8.
Приложение на Java, JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

convmv, есть вроде и под окнами тоже, в линухе:

`convmv -f CP1251 -t utf8 * -r --notest`

Comment: Чего-то не работает. У меня Windows XP.
Как я понял, надо просто закопипастить эту вашу строку?

Comment: Слежует установить convmv, и да можно воспользоваться той строкой, но лучше посмотреть ключи, может под окнами что-то по другому.

Answer (score 1):

У Far manager - http://www.farmanager.com/download.php

есть плагин transod который умеет менять кодировку файлов, может в пакетном режиме

Comment: ссылка на плагин http://plugring.farmanager.com/plugin.php?pid=141&l=ru

Answer (score 1):

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import os
def decodeRecursive(path, baseCharset, targetCharset):
    folder=os.listdir(path)
    for name in folder:
        if os.path.isdir(path+'/'+name):
            decodeRecursive(path+'/'+name, baseCharset, targetCharset)
        else:
            try:
                f=open(path+'/'+name, 'r')
                text=unicode(f.read(), baseCharset)
                f.close()
                tmp=text.encode(targetCharset)
                f=open(path+'/'+name, 'w')
                f.write(tmp)
                f.close()
                print 'OK:  '+path+'/'+name
            except:
                print 'ERR: '+path+'/'+name

decodeRecursive('/var/www/test', 'cp1251', 'utf-8')
```

Можно сделать так, правда нужен Python

Answer (score 0):

enconv в Linux
Под виндами notepad++ умеет, но это будет долго, если файлов много.

Comment: Вот именно, что 400. Как быстрее?

Comment: Должно подойти: http://www.john.geek.nz/2010/02/enca-binary-compiled-for-32-bit-windows/

Comment: Только работайте с копией, пожалуйста :-)